# coding style dilemma in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I want to accomplish different environment for my node.js + mongodb project. eg. (development,staging, production).
Its a dynamic website actually. the problem is how do separate only segments of code depending on the environment. 70 % code is same on every environment .
Solutions in mind :
1. Maintain copies of project for every env . [will take a lot of space.]
2. Change only segment of code in the files acc to env .[Mess up the code]

Please note that I am not talking about changing the db connections or minute changes acc to env...for eg. consider a page "demohtml.jade". 80% code is sme except the hyperlinks .I want links of env-1 to point to routes of env-1 and similarly links of env-2 to point to routes of env-2.and accordingly maintain different routes .these routes also carry same code maximum time which is not a good approach acc to me.

Looking for a cleaner approach to take .Please suggest

Comment: What kind of difference do you have between environments? Different functionality? Use strategy / adapter pattern to solve it …

Comment: yeah..only 20 % functionality differs , what pattern are you talking about ?

Comment: Software development patterns, to fully use power of polymorphism - same method invocation but different implementations according to environment … E.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

Comment: Thanks...will read the link ...